# Replacing a avg pool layer with a conv layer

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have an average pool layer with kernel size (4,3), which also has a stride of (4,3) and 0 padding. I want to convert this to its equivalent conv layer for implementation in my neural network.

So, in my model, I replaced this:

```
self.pool = nn.AvgPool2d((4, 3))
```

With this line (32 is the number of input channels):

```
self.pool = nn.Conv2d(32, 32, (4, 3), stride=(4, 3), bias=False)
```

To me, it seems like these both should be equivalent, and the output sizes for both of these layers is (1, 32, 32, 13) (it has 32 channels); for an input of the size (1, 32, 129, 40) (32 channels, X dimension 129 and Y dimension 40).

I want the avg pool operation to be replaced by a conv layer so that both produce the same output. Can this be done?

Comment: I don't understand what the actual question is.

Comment: Edited, question should be more clear now

Answer (score 2):

They will result in the same output shape. Here's a quick test confirm:

```
import torch

data = torch.zeros(1, 32, 129, 40)
print(torch.nn.AvgPool2d((4, 3))(data).shape,
      torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 32, (4, 3), stride=(4, 3))(data).shape)
```

```
torch.Size([1, 32, 32, 13])
torch.Size([1, 32, 32, 13])
```

Their resulting shapes are the same in this case, but they're not equivalent operations. Average pooling takes one channel at a time, ignoring every other channel. It pools over each channel independently, which is why the number of output channels matches the number of input channels.

The conv layer scans over all 32 channels simultaneously, producing one output channel per conv filter. Thus, for a conv layer, the number of output channels is determined by how many filters the conv layer has, rather than the number of input channels. In this case you configured the conv layer with 32 filters, so it happens to have an output channel size (n_filters or n_out=32) that's the same as the input channel size (n_in=32).

The pooling operation provides a coarse summary of features. By swapping it out for a conv layer, you introduce more learnable parameters.